# How to ensure plugin manager is installed

Tags: vim, vi

I would like to check at the top of my `.vimrc` whether vim-plug is installed and act accordingly so whenever I install my dotfiles, I don't get errors after running vim for the first time.

If there is no vim-plug, then wget should download it from github and install plugins.

So far I have this code snippet

```
if empty(glob("~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim"))
  execute '!mkdir ~/.vim/autoload && wget -O ~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim'
endif

call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')
  " plugins...
call plug#end()
```

But this just makes sure vim-plug is present in the plugin directory.
How can I load this plugin after download and issue PlugInstall after `call plug#end()`?

Thank you for help!

**Edit**
I partially managed to solve the rpoblem by adding

```
autocmd VimEnter * PlugInstall --sync | source $MYVIMRC
```

Unfortunately some errors still occur.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To check whether plugin loaded or not you should deal with its implemented features. **vim-plug** provides several commands and functions so you can do `exists("*plug#begin")` or `exists(":PlugInstall")`. Since you call `PlugInstall` I would recommend the last one. For more information type `help exists(`.

Friendly speaking, the goal is very weird since there can be no internet connection or plugin destination can be changed by the maintainer. Nevertheless, if you prefer this behavior here are some tips:

1. Use `-p` flag for `mkdir`. Command will not fail if there is already **autoload** directory.
2. Use vim `system()` function to call the shell command; then check `v:shell_error` for issues I mentioned above. It should be 0 if no errors happen.